# Insert DataGridVIew Cell Value in Database Table

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms, datagridview

I'm fairly new to programming with c#.

So I have created database table Info with columns ID, PersonName, City, and binded it to DataGridView in WinForms. Whenever i change cell value or add a new cell, I want it to update/insert respectively into the db table. My question is which event I should you? I have tried CellEndEdit, CellValueChanged, CellLeave, and none seems to be working.

This is my INSERT Query:

```
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Info([PersonName], [City]) Values (@personName, @city)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@personName", dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString());

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            dataGridView1.ResetBindings();
            conn.Close();
```

And for the UPDATE Query

```
            conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        string updateQuery = "update Info set [PersonName]='" + dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value + "', [City]='" + dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value + "', where ID=" + dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0] + "";
        cmd.CommandText = updateQuery;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
```

I'm aware that for CellLeave event it might not be getting the right cells, but have no idea as to why the other events aren't working.

Anyone want to share any t

Comment: The *easiest* way is to use a DataTable as a DataSource filled by a persistent DataAdapter.  The DGV automatically saves the changes/adds and deletes tot he DataTable.  The DA can then save changes to dozens or hundreds of rows with one `Update` statement,

Answer (score 0):

You are using the right event but use it like below. SelectedCells may not return the right value. use the e.RowIndex which will return the value for exact Cell that you were editing.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
         string Person = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Person"].Value.ToString();
         string City = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["City"].Value.ToString();
         AddToDatabase(Person,City);
    }
```